# javascript random bg image cells

Tags: javascript, css, image

I want different cells to have a random background image. Please let me know what is wrong with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = new Array("px/1.png","px/2.png","px/3.png","px/4.png","px/5.png")
    onload=function() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*images.length-1)
    td1.style.background="url('"+images[rand]+"')"
    }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
td {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td2" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td3" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td4" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td5" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Sorry 1rst time   
I want one class style like  .td1 in different cells   
And have every cell a different random bg-image  
It works with one cell and id  
Help please